# Relative Layout Error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-relativelayout

can someone help me to check what is the problem for crashing?? the layout i want is something like
<

Opp SAFRA Tampines

5

Pasir Ris Int                      (ImageButton)

15:23   15:28    15:30

---

15

Tampines Int

15:23   15:26    15:39

>

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FFFFF0"
        android:text="Opp SAFRA Tampines"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view0"
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bus5"
        android:layout_width="125px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view0"
        android:background="#E7FEFF"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:text="  5"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text02"
        android:layout_width="850px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#E7FEFF"
        android:text="  Pasir Ris Int"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/text02"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bux5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/chart" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text03"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text02"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chart"
        android:background="#E7FEFF"
        android:text="  15:25   15:36    15:47"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text03"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text04"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text03"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
        android:background="#E7FEFF"
        android:stretchColumns="2"
        android:text="  15"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text05"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text04"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text04"
        android:background="#E7FEFF"
        android:text="  Tampines Int"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:width="850px" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text06"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text05"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text05"
        android:background="#E7FEFF"
        android:text="  15:23   15:28    15:30"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text06"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text07"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text06"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
        android:background="#E7FEFF"
        android:stretchColumns="2"
        android:text="  21"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text08"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text07"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text07"
        android:background="#E7FEFF"
        android:text="  Pasir Ris Int"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:width="850px" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text09"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text08"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text08"
        android:background="#E7FEFF"
        android:text="  15:23   15:26    15:39"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text09"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text09"
        android:background="#E7FEFF"
        android:stretchColumns="2"
        android:text="  23"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text10"
        android:background="#E7FEFF"
        android:text="  Tampines Int"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:width="850px" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text11"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text11"
        android:background="#E7FEFF"
        android:text="  15:29   15:30    15:39"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view4"
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text12"
        android:background="#FF0000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Arash now theres no error, but layout format weird, the top all mess together

Comment: where is the closing `ScrollView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, you see you have to put the closing `</ScrollView>` tag in the last line of this xml document.

your scrollview is the parent tag and the you have closed it with relative layout tag, just put the `</ScrollView>` tag in last line

Comment: sorry i did not get you, i implemented the following code and added the closing tag, and it worked. Please tell the problem more briefly.